# Cocoa WebView, WebKit - Prevent I-Beam cursor from showing over text?

Tags: html, cocoa, cursor, webview

Cocoa app, SnowLeopard

I have a WebView in to which I'm loading HTML (essentially for application UI purposes).

In the html, I've added:

```
<body onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false">
```

This prevents text from being selected, which is what I want for this job.

However, whenever the cursor is moved over any text, including disabled "button" texts, the cursor changes to the I-Beam, producing a nasty, unwanted effect.

Is there any way to change this behaviour, either in HTML or in WebKit?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `-webkit-user-select: none;` declaration to each of the selectors you don't want to be user-selectable.

Actually, if you just want to show a different cursor, use this:

```
#myelement {
    cursor: default;
}
```

This will show a regular pointer instead of the selection I-Beam.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Alas, this is not having any effect. (The I-Beam still appears over any text.)

Comment: Try using the cursor declaration above, it might be what you're looking for.