# HTML - Don't show hand cursor over links? (Cocoa, WebView, WebKit)

Tags: html, webkit, cursor

Cocoa, Snow Leopard, Tiger compatibility needed.

I have a WebView containing some HTML. The HTML contains links, and is used mostly as a UI replacement for Cocoa.

Question: how do I prevent the 'hand' cursor from appearing when the mouse is moved over a link? For aesthetic reasons with this particular UI, I need it to stay as the arrow cursor at all times.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Cocoa WebView, WebKit - Prevent I-Beam cursor from showing over text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464111/cocoa-webview-webkit-prevent-i-beam-cursor-from-showing-over-text)

They seemed to have a similar question, is that what you're asking?

EDIT: Haha sorry, I didn't realize that was you! Perhaps you could use that method for #a:hover ?

---

Take a look at http://trac.webkit.org/export/37902/trunk/WebCore/manual-tests/cursor.html it has a lot of different webkit cursors. The source code should be helpful as well

And from what I can tell `cursor:default` should make the arrow (from reading the source code)

Comment: That is indeed me! Yes, it's a related issue.  From what I can tell, using cursor:default will not actually show the arrow cursor, rather it's telling the browser to use the default cursor for that element.  In this case, a hand cursor, which is not what I need.  Cheers.

Comment: SirRatty, I addded a link on some common cursons in WebKit, does that help?

Comment: `cursor:auto` uses the default cursor for that element. `cursor:default` _does_ use the standard arrow cursor; this is the one you want.